# can trigger an airflow job in sub seconds?

Tags: airflow

I tried to trigger an airflow job more than two times in a second via airflow rest api and found that only a trigger was successful. And if scheduling an airflow job, the minimum time is 1 second.

So any approach to trigger an airflow job in sub seconds?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't describe your use case, but mainly saying- Apache Airflow is built for scheduled batch jobs, I suggest you don't go below the hourly interval.
If you find yourself with a need for more frequent processing, maybe Airflow is not the platform for you, and if we're talking about sub seconds, consider to choose a streaming platform, like [Kafka Streams](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/index.html), [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/), [NiFi](https://nifi.apache.org/) or [StreamSets](https://streamsets.com/).